# Can one row key exist in multiple hbase regions?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hbase

As per my understanding, HBase Tables are divided horizontally by row key range into “Regions.” A region contains all rows in the table between the region's start key and end key.

Suppose I have a row which is very large (consider it is more than the configured maximum region size itself) then how will it be stored in one region. Will it be spitted and stored across multiple regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row lives entirely within one region. All other keys would be moved out of that region in order to best meet the maximum region size. I suppose if you actually encounter this situation then it's a sign that you need to revisit your key design.